# What is the principle for behavior of boost adding month?

Tags: c++, date, boost

[example of boost add month](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.general_usage_examples)

[28/02/2009 + 1 month = 31/03/2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423961/easy-way-to-add-1-month-to-a-time-t-in-c-c)

```
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian_types.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/gregorian/formatters.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::gregorian;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
typedef boost::date_time::month_functor<date> add_month;
        date d(2019, Feb, 28);
        add_month mf(1);
        date d2 = d + mf.get_offset(d);
        cout << to_simple_string(d2) << endl;//output:2019-Mar-31
}
```

The output is 2019-Mar-31 rather than 2019-Mar-28. What is theoretical basis for this behavior? Talk about it outputs 2019-Mar-28 in both C# and delphi for the similar add month code.

Answer (score 8):

This behavior is mentioned in the documentation of [**`boost::date_time::month_functor`**](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/date_time/month_functor.html).

> This adjustment function provides the logic for 'month-based' advancement on a ymd based calendar. The policy it uses to handle the non existant end of month days is to back up to the last day of the month. **Also, if the starting date is the last day of a month, this functor will attempt to adjust to the end of the month**.

So adding a month to February 28th will result in March 31st.
But adding a month to February 27th will result in March 27th.

See [**`LIVE DEMO.`**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hEcSXWqP5CZGIxUs)

Comment: @Zhang: Does this answer your question?